# fast report условие

Tags: fastreport

Редактирую FRX отчет. Условие такое, если set=null и department_i не равно  !=32,33,34,7 тогда выводить исполнитель не привязан.
Дело в том что если я пишу так

```
[IIf([QryZO.set] == null, "Исполнитель не привязан", [QryZO.set])]
```

То отчет формирует

как мне добавить условие И? `[QryZO.department_i] !=32,33,34,7`

Comment: обернуть в скобки оба условия и поставить между ними булевое И?

Answer (score 0):

вы можете написать свою собственную функцию в сценарии отчета и вызвать ее в дизайнере
например:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using FastReport;
using FastReport.Data;
using FastReport.Dialog;
using FastReport.Barcode;
using FastReport.Table;
using FastReport.Utils;

namespace FastReport
{
  public class ReportScript
  {
    public string Compare(int[] array)
    {
      foreach(var item in array)
      {
        if(item == 38 || item == 7 || item == 43 )
        {
           return "not OK ";
         
        }
        
      }
      return "OK";
    }
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, на русский, нажав [edit]